# What is the easiest way to automatically collect user data in a prototype app?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, prototype, app, tools

I would like to test the design for an app. Therefore, I would like to let my test subjects use an app prototype on their smartphones for a few days in a row. I would like the test persons to use the app as naturally as possible without creating a specific test situation. For testing, I want to automatically collect user data, especially whether links were clicked or how much time the subjects took with the app.

Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with programming. I therefore don't feel up to create a "real" app myself. I have worked with Axure before, but I don't feel that the software meets my needs since user input is not saved as soon the shared link is closed. It is also unclear to me how data could be automatically saved on an external server.

Does anyone know of any software, good workarounds, or other solutions that might help me?

Comment: Much of the benefit of user testing will be lost without watching the user use the app and having them walk you through their thoughts - but if that's not your goal, you can simply add a Google Analytics tag to your Axure Cloud prototype, as seen here: https://forum.axure.com/t/google-analytics-for-user-testing-in-axure-rp9/68567

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a service like trymyui.com where it records the user interacting with your prototype.